# Open search bar when click on right bar button item in navigation bar?

Tags: swift

```
**** open a search bar when i click on right navigation bar button action.****

i have  a view controller and on the right side of  the controller there is a search bar button item so on the action of button i want to open a search bar.
```

so i don't know how to open search on button click 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the screenshot of UI and if there is a searchbar already and you want to move the cursor and open keyboard to there is new page? Can't solve without your UI shot.

Answer (score 1):

If you use UITableView, you can add UISearchBar to UITableView's tableViewHeader property. You can show UISearchBar by change UITableView contentOffset property. A basic example below:

```
final class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var searchBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

private let datasource = ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6"]

private lazy var dataSearchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 44.0))
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search..."
    return searchBar
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = dataSearchBar
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    var contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
    contentOffset.y = contentOffset.y + (self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame ?? CGRect()).height
    self.tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset
}

@IBAction func didTap(searchBarbuttonItem barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    datasource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = datasource[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

}
```

[UI Preview](https://gfycat.com/unknowncreativeantarcticgiantpetrel)